# Python beautiful soup get only body content without header or footer data

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests, request

In my code I need to get only the main text not the header or footer data. I also would like to filter out any html/css/js code that is received with the request. How would I do this? I have tried making a request with requests, looking through the data with  beautiful soup and then printing the body content. The issue with this is that it is also picking up the footer and header contents. Thanks for any responses in advance!

Comment: Please provide some code and examples which you are working on so people can help you and understand your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the browser developer tools (Usually F12) to find out what element contains the content you are looking for. Usually content other than headers and footers will be in `<section>` or `<article>` elements.

You can then use something like `soup.article.get_text()` to retrieve text from the containing element.